# Razer Blade 14" 2016: can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am attempting to set up dual-boot Ubuntu on my 2016 Blade 14".

I am booting from a USB stick. It makes it past GRUB into the Ubuntu boot process, and then hangs. I have tried with Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 as well as the latest Linux Mint (all 64-bit versions). All have the same result.

I am attaching a screen photo of the dmsg output from booting Ubuntu 16.04. (cross posted to [Razer forums](https://insider.razerzone.com/index.php?threads/blade-14-2016-cant-boot-ubuntu.14185/))

[image]

Comment: Is your laptop overclocked?

Comment: not unless they did that at the factory, which i am pretty sure they did not. i have done literally nothing to this brand-new system other than try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: also i have tried running the Intel CPU diagnostic tool (under windows) and it finds no problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 4):

That's a "nouveau" problem, the nvidia open source driver causing this problem. if you add nouveau.modeset=0 as a boot-up kernel perimeter it will boot with the intel card only which will allow you to install the proprietary nvidia driver.
I have the same laptop and had the same issue in Fedora and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As for now it look like the kernel and drivers delivered with Ubuntu 16.04 are to old for your Laptop.

We may can work around it but that requires some hardware details.

For further information I need to know the content for your grub.cfg or the output of:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

Comment: i've tested the USB stick i am booting from on another system and it works perfectly. does that eliminate possibility #2?

Comment: Not entirely, but most, it cloud still be releated to the  boot arguments.  but that is fixable.

Comment: here are the contents of grub.cfg: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95f83a57a3a75d63e1edd40b25448c63

Comment: I made a comment on your github filefor line 15: ---  linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---  
+++linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper verbose maxcpu=1 no_splash ---  Try booting with this options, and post the result.

Comment: i added the output to the gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95f83a57a3a75d63e1edd40b25448c63 -- the same thing is happening, but now it shows CPU 1 instead of CPU 6 is hanging.

Comment: Now, I see, its a grafical Issue. Do you know with CPU and GPU are buid in your device? If, please post it, you probal need a diifernd kernel, or modules.

Comment: core i7–6700HQ processor and GeForce GTX 970M graphics

Comment: i thought so, the problem belongs to the hardfwar be newer than the kernel. You may just have to wait until driver get updated or create a new system from scratch see [here](http://trac.clfs.org/wiki "Linux from Scratch") but that requires some amout of Linux knowlage already.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but if you found this post while googling, here is a fix:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/5e83gy/rough_guide_to_installing_ubuntu_gnome_on_the/

Comment: Rather than posting a Link to another site, could you instead only use it as a reference link?  Providing a little Step by Step tutorial is closer to what is needed. :)